# htaccess: rewrite to optional amount of "subfolders" www.xyz.com/a/b/c/d

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

sorry for my bad english and wrong use of technical terms.

So I got these links on my site:

```
www.xyz.com/index.php?link=abc
```

I want to rewrite via htaccess like this:

```
www.xyz.com/def/.../jki/abc
```

/.../ meaning that I want to be able to be as flexible with my "link-design" as I want.

I tried it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^.+/([a-z-.-?]+) index.php?link=$1 [NC,L]
```

and it works, but the strange part is, that it doesnt work all the time, or it totally stops working. Sometimes images and css is not being loaded anymore.

Then I switched to test it with

```
RewriteRule ^.+/m/([a-z-.-?]+) index.php?link=$1 [NC,L]
```

and this works fine, but I'm abviously stuck with the /m/-part like:

```
www.xyz.com/def/.../jki/m/abc
```

Is there even any option to do this?

Thank you very much.